# How to set entry point after building the image in docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize my django application and my Django has a dependency with GDAL and I added the dependency command in `Dockerfile`.

The content in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install python -y

RUN apt install python3-pip -y

RUN apt install python3-dev libpq-dev -y

RUN apt-get install gdal-bin

RUN apt-get install libgdal-dev

RUN apt install sudo

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python3","manage.py" , "runserver" , "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

So, the problem here is that 6th line will ask for timezone like to select from `1-99` how can I pass those too as an argument in this file.

So, to solve the above issue I remove line `6 and 7` and also the `last line` and installed it via `docker run -it <image_name>` and I committed it to a new image and now I can't execute the command I need which is `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: Your line numbers don't seem to make sense here. Are you asking how to pass input to `apt-get install` when it wants to configure a package?

Comment: You should be able to `RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...` (all packages in a single command) and you won't get prompted.

Comment: @tripleee yes that what I’m asking